# Copying from istream never stops

Tags: c++, istream, istream-iterator

This bit of code runs infinitely:

```
copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), back_inserter(buff));
```

The behavior I was expecting is that it will stop when I press enter.
However it doesn't.
buff is a vector of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are typing stuff in at the keyboard.

The enter key doesn't signify the end of the stream. It's just another character from cin's perspective. You need to submit EOF to achieve this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Unix/Mac).

Incidentally, this isn't the usual way to read characters from the console. It is very inefficient (`istream_iterator` calls `operator>>` for each character) and will misbehave with whitespace. To read a line of data entry, use `getline` instead.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that I am coding this wrong?

Comment: Yes; I've amended the question to reflect what I think you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried getline but it doesn't work with a vector.
It works when I cin >> tempstring; and then copy it into the vector however it is very inefficient in my opinion.

Comment: You are supposed to use it with a std::string, not a vector. Copying to a vector is at least ten million times faster than your typing speed, so efficiency is hardly an issue. In any case, you should be able to do pretty much anything with a string that you can with a vector.

Comment: BTW, `cin >> tempstring` doesn't read lines, it reads until the next whitespace.

Comment: For better performance, `istreambuf_iterator<char>(cin)` could be used too. That's faster since it won't do formatting and all that.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Could you demonstrate how such code will look like?

Comment: @the_drow exactly like your code just with the iterator names changed :)